# Combined Effect of Steric Inhibition of Resonance and Inductive Effect

Tags: inductive-effect, steric-effects

While qualitatively comparing the acidic nature of *o*-methyl benzoic acid and benzoic acid, we consider the steric effect due to which the $\ce{-COOH}$ group loses its planarity and the +M effect of $\ce{-CH3}$ isn't considered any longer. But still, the +I of $\ce{CH3}$ is functioning, which increases the electron density of the compound and reduces its acidity. Thus *o*-methyl benzoic acid should be less acidic than benzoic acid. But while confirming my results with the experimental data, I found that $\ce{pK_a}$ of *o*-methyl benzoic acid is 3.90 while that of benzoic acid is 4.20. How can this be explained using the basic concepts of electronic displacement effects?

[image]
[image: Text]

Comment: +I is a *very* weak effect compared to loss of coplanarity due to sterics.

Comment: the grouping $ \ce {-CH_3} $ is too far for its + I effect to be felt on the acidity